# Is there any framework that supports Websocket and falls back to other methods when it is not supported on client's browser?

Tags: ajax, websocket

I was doing AJAX implementation and would like to use Websocket when the client web browser supports it. Is there any frameworks that supports Websocket but falls-back to other methods when it detects the client side doesn't support Websocket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes sort of see www.kaazing.org

Kaazing Gateway supports all major browsers (Firefox version 1.5 and higher, Internet Explorer version 5.5 and higher, Safari version 3.0 and higher, Opera version 9.5 and higher, and Google Chrome version 0.2 and higher).

Answer (score 6):

There is also Atmosphere

```
http://atmosphere.dev.java.net
```

which support both client and server.

Answer (score 4):

Socket.io is designed for this.

http://socket.io/

It is purely javascript that tries several different transport methods including XHR long-polling, WebSocket and FlashSocket amongst others.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Nirvana from www.my-channels.com.

When WebSocket is not supported it will fall back to a Comet based approach transparently.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you could try using jWebSocket, it is a pure Java/JavaScript high speed bidirectional communication solution for the Web - secure, reliable and fast. jWebSocket is provided to you to create innovative HTML5 based streaming and communication applications on the web. HTML5 WebSockets will replace the existing XHR approaches as well as Comet services by a new flexible and ultra high speed bidirectional TCP socket communication technology. jWebSocket is an open source Java and JavaScript implementation of the HTML5 WebSocket protocol with a huge set of extensions. Some demos or examples can be seen for you in the website, you can visit it here: https://jwebsocket.org/